# java exception handling and continuation

Tags: java

I have a Java Program where I get data from a different source. some times while reading I see Exception and the program is exiting.
Mine is in a program that runs every 10minutes.

```
Public static void main(Strings[] args)
{
...readsource();
}

Private static void readsource() throws IOException
{
...
}
```

Issue:
I am able to get/See the Exception. But I want the program to continue
To that what is the best logic? I dont see try-catch-finally also is not addressing ..I want the program to continue even after seing the exception (I mean the next iteration should continue). This looks to be a Basic issue not sure how to address this...

Comment: Preferably pasting something that you execute with as little modification as you can -- you've got uppercase visibility modifiers and no sign of a try/catch as thinksteep says.

Comment: There was some login issue with the program. was looking at the wrong one Thankq and corrected the try/catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to catch the exception, which you are currently not doing.

```
try  {
    readsource();
} catch (IOException e) {
   // do something, never catch an exception and not do anything
}

//continue.
```

Note that exceptions usually indicate something is wrong.   Unless you are going to do something about the exception, it might be better to fix the condition causing the exception....

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide an error handler in your method, i.e. surround the call to readsource() with a try-catch block.

```
   public static void main(Strings[] args)
   {
      try{
         ...readsource();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe){
           //handle the error here,e.g don't do anything or simply log it
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't rethrow the exception in the catch block, execution will fall off the end of the catch block and continue as if there was no exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you'd like to recall the method wether an Exception was thrown or not just place this in a while loop i.e:

```
Public static void main(Strings[] args)
{
    boolean run=true;
    while(run) {
    try {
            System.out.print("Hello,");
            readsource();
            throw new IOException();
            if(1==2)run=false;//stop the loop for whatever condition
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" world!");
    }
   }

}

Private static void readsource() throws IOException
{
...
}
```